# I want to download code from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to update the app in google app store.
But I can't download the code...

Is there any way to update the app without downloading the code?

I tried to download with python, google app engine SDK...

But
appcfg.py download_app -A

This command does not work giving this error

NameError: global name 'execfile' is not defined...

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you have shown may occur due to incorrect PYTHONPATH environment variable.

If you are using the Windows version of the GAE SDK, then do the following:

1) Go to Edit > Preferences

2) Correct your Python Path.

To know the Python Path in windows do the following in the Python IDLE or Python CMD:

```
import os

import sys

print os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

For downloading your source code try this:

```
download_app -A app_name -V version C:\path_to_project
```

You may or may not need to escape the backslash.

Replace app_name, version and C:\path_to_project with appropriate values

To know the version go to the app engine admin website [appengine.appspot.com](http://appengine.appspot.com)